# Android Design - How to get this card view effect?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am creating a weather app.
How do I get this card effect ? How do I get a textView in a card like that ?

[image]

This is my status:

[image]

Can someone show how to make this or something at least similar

Comment: use recyclerview and cardview for your list

Comment: Your issue is not about the Android Studio usage, is about Android programming. As @HRaval says, use cardview and recycler view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frist of all below dependencies add in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
```

and in xml you can write this code. its just sample design according to your need...

this will solve your question... How do I get this card effect ? How do I get a textView in a card like that ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Detail"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_below="@id/text1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TUE"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NOON"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlackLight"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EVE"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlackLight"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NIGHT"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlackLight"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WED"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WED"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlackLight"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="21"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlackLight"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_like_icon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text8"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textmore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MORE"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlackLight"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

you can use this xml in row.xml for using in recyclerview to create multiple use
for listing read tutorial:

```
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view
```

hope it will helpfull for you. dont forgot to **`accept`** it if helpfull